# key of type -> boolean is not assignable to type never

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't understand why I become in my Angular project the TypeScript error `Type boolean is not assignable to type never` when I try to set a value to the `testObject`.

```
export interface TestInterface {
  text: string;
  number: number;
  bool1: boolean;
  bool2: boolean;
}
```

```
export class DamagesComponent implements OnInit {
  testObject: TestInterface = {
    text: 'test String',
    number: 22,
    bool1: false,
    bool2: true
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toogleVal('bool1')
  }

  toogleVal(key: keyof TestInterface): void {
    if (key in this.testObject) {
      if (typeof this.testObject[key] === 'boolean') {
        // here the error
        this.testObject[key] = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are accessing the property dynamically, you need to specify in the interface that the key will be a string and the return type will be some data type, the error will go away by modifying the interface to.

```
export interface TestInterface {
  text: string;
  number: number;
  bool1: boolean;
  bool2: boolean;
  // this needs to be at the bottom for it to accept the default datatypes of the properties set already!
  [key: string]: string | boolean | number;
  // [key: string]: any; // or with any data type which is less preferred!
}
```

[Online Typescript editor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Comment: thanks for the fast answer – works perfect!

Comment: @miholzi You're welcome!